# PHP SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 6

Tags: php, json

I'm a beginner in coding and i need your help.
I'm trying to have a valide json but i have this error :

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 6 column 35 of the JSON data

I tried this regex in my php file: 
`preg_match_all("/<[\s]*meta[\s]*name='?" . "([^>']*)'?[\s]*" . "content='?([^>']*)'?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si", $contents, $match);`

And my Json give me that (see the pic in attach to see what's inside "html"):

`

```
{
    "CMS": "tumblr",
    "title": "Le Blog de Betty - Le Blog de Betty : Blog mode, blog tendances, photos de mode par Betty Autier",
    "metaTags": {
        "viewport": {
            "html": "",
            "content": "width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"
        },
        "description": {
            "html": "",
            "content": "Le Blog de Betty : Blog mode, blog tendances, photos de mode par Betty Autier"
        },
        "generator": {
            "html": "",
            "content": "WPML ver:3.1.8.3 stt:4,1,2,65;0"
        },
        "og:locale": {
            "html": "",
            "content": "fr_FR"
        },
        "og:type": {
            "html": "",
            "content": "website"
        },
        "og:title": {
            "html": "",
            "content": "Le Blog de Betty - Le Blog de Betty : Blog mode, blog tendances, photos de mode par Betty Autier"
        },
        "og:description": {
            "html": "",
            "content": "Le Blog de Betty : Blog mode, blog tendances, photos de mode par Betty Autier"
        },
        "og:url": {
            "html": "",
            "content": "http://leblogdebetty.com/"
        },
        "og:site_name": {
            "html": "",
            "content": "Le Blog de Betty"
        },
        "article:publisher": {
            "html": "",
            "content": "http://facebook.com/leblogdebetty"
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "shortcut icon": {
            "html": "",
            "href": "http://localhost:8888/images/2013/12/favicon.ico"
        },
        "canonical": {
            "html": "",
            "href": "http://leblogdebetty.com/"
        },
        "next": {
            "html": "",
            "href": "http://leblogdebetty.com/page/2/"
        },
        "publisher": {
            "html": "",
            "href": "https://plus.google.com/+leblogdebetty"
        },
        "'dns-prefetch' ": {
            "html": "",
            "href": "'//s.w.org' /"
        },
        "stylesheet": {
            "html": "",
            "href": "http://leblogdebetty.com/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/css/jetpack.css?ver=3.4.3"
        },
        "'https://api.w.org/' ": {
            "html": "",
            "href": "'http://leblogdebetty.com/wp-json/' /"
        }
    }
}
```

`

[Part of Json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYiUV.png)

Can someone help me to solve that please ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the values from the Json?

Comment: take a look at the following: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

Comment: the json in the image has unescaped quotes and is not valid `meta\nname="viewport"....`

Comment: @kishor : I am trying to get a valid Json and i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlentities()` function on the appropriate fields to convert the quotationmarks to their `&quot;` representation.

You can also try `addslashes()` which escapes from `"` to `\"`.

Comment: Should be accepted answer.  You may need to iterate over your result set calling this on each field.